# android org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject?

Tags: android

```
 [{"Episode Detail":[{"Episode-image":"http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/episode_image\/014929Quincredible_1-6.png","Episode-description":" dsdsdsdsds ","Episode-video":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/KhXTLAdadlw"},{"Episode-image":"http:\/\/app.lionforge.com\/comics\/adminpanel\/episode_image\/015041Quincredible_1-5.png","Episode-description":" avbcabc ","Episode-video":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/embed\/5ORBHSJhXew"}]}]


   JSONObject jObject=null;
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray list = jObject.getJSONArray("Episode Detail");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject element = list.getJSONObject(i);
                episodebean bean=new episodebean();
```

i am getting json exception  that JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject,how i resolve this ,i am so confuse..,please help me..

Comment: You should accept one of the below answer that helped you most as it seems your problem solved. and you have asked nearly 10 questions and accepted none...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
jObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

To

```
 JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(response);
```

JSON

```
[  //json array node 
    { // json object node 
        "Episode Detail": [ // json array episode detail
            {            // json obect node j
                "Episode-image":  "http://app.lionforge.com/comics/adminpanel/episode_image/014929Quincredible_1-6.png", 
                "Episode-description": " dsdsdsdsds ",
                "Episode-video": "http://www.youtube.com/embed/KhXTLAdadlw"
            },
            {
                "Episode-image": "http://app.lionforge.com/comics/adminpanel/episode_image/015041Quincredible_1-5.png",
                "Episode-description": " avbcabc ",
                "Episode-video": "http://www.youtube.com/embed/5ORBHSJhXew"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4):

use following code

```
JSONObject jObject=null;
    try {
        JSONArray array = new JsonArray(response)
        jObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray list = jObject.getJSONArray("Episode Detail");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject element = list.getJSONObject(i);
                episodebean bean=new episodebean();
```

your have one `jsonArray` that has one `JsonObject`

Answer (score 3):

```
JSONArray arr  = new JSONArray("");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = json_data.getJSONObject(i);
        JSONArray arrdata = c.getJSONArray("Episode Detail");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The root of your `JSON` is an `JSONArray`

Answer (score 0):

response is Array not object.

```
jObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

it should be Array instead of object